# Add OpenSSL static libraries to a vc++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl, static-libraries

I have some problems adding the OpenSSL libraries to my visual vc++ project.

I tried everything I could find but I am still unable to include any `.h` files in my code.

I have a directory where I put my `.lib` (`libeay32.lib` and `ssleay32.lib`) libraries in a sub directory of my project called "Lib". I also have a environment variable pointing to my OpenSSL installation folder called "OPENSSL". Here's some screenshots of my project's config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Still with all that if I write `#include "rsa.h` for example, Visual Studio tells me it doesn't exist. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried including like this:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
```

or

```
#include <rsa.h>
```

Which proper way of including is the first one, unless you've added inside of openssl folder in your include path

Comment: I have the same message for all the possibilities : "error: cannot open source file XXX"

Comment: @jumojer, confirm environment variable by echo in command prompt, see if it exists and if it points to right folder: echo %OPENSSL%

Comment: @jumojer, can you do "dir %OPENSSL%\openssl\rsa.h" and confirm that such file exists.

Comment: %OPENSSL%\openssl\rsa.h doesnt exist. The correct path to the rsa.h file is %OPENSSL%\include\rsa.h

Comment: Can you just remove environment variable and try C:\openssl\include\ as it is and C:\openssl\lib\ in include and additional library settings of your projects, then do #include <rsa.h> and check to see if it works or not?

Comment: it does reconize the rsa.h file with absolute paths. Ill try to work from that thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome. Don't forget #include "something.h" is ONLY when .h file is in your project folder not in include directories, for those use <>.